# Regular expression not matching on first and last word of string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a java program that will look for a specific words in a string. I have it working for the most part but it doesnt seem to match if the word to match is the first or last word in the string.  Here is an example:

```
"trying to find the first word".matches(".*[^a-z]find[^a-z].*") //returns true
"trying to find the first word".matches(".*[^a-z]trying[^a-z].*") //returns false
"trying to find the first word".matches(".*[^a-z]word[^a-z].*") //returns false
```

Any idea how to make this match on any word in the string?

Thanks in advance,

Craig

Comment: `\bWORD\b` as `\b` is the "word boundary" anchor. Relevant reading: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: any reason why you are not just using `String.contains(String)`?

Comment: im not using contains because i dont want to find words inside of others (ie if im looking for burn, burned would be true)

i tried putting \b but it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: `"trying to find the first word".matches(".*\\btrying\\b.*")`

Comment: looks like that worked!  i guess java requires the backslash to properly process \b?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your character class before and after the words `[^a-z]`- I think that what you actually want is a word boundary character `\b` (as per ColinD's comment) as opposed to not a character in the a-z range. As pointed out in the comments (thanks) you'll also needs to handle the start and end of string cases.

So try, eg:

```
"(?:^|.*\b)trying(?:\b.*|$)"
```

Comment: Won't `\W` fail to match `^` and `$`? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: The comment of @CollinD to the question is correct. This answer will not work, because the character class "[]" matches exactly one character. At the beginning, there is no preceding character.

Comment: `\B` is actually the non-word-boundary anchor. `\b` is for word boundaries.

Comment: Rich: Not yet, `\W` won't work either, pick @CollinD's `\b`.

Comment: when i run it with a \b before and after the word it still evaluates to false :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional (?) , check below link and test more cases if this give proper output:
https://regex101.com/r/oP5zB8/1

```
 (.*[^a-z]?trying[^a-z]?.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `(^|^.*[^a-z])trying([^a-z].*$|$)` just fits your need.

Or `(?:^|^.*[^a-z])trying(?:[^a-z].*$|$)` for non capturing parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following program to check the existence on start and end of any string:

```
package com.ajsodhi.utilities;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegExStartEndWordCheck {

    public static final String stringToMatch = "StartingsomeWordsEndWord";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String regEx = "Starting[A-Za-z0-9]{0,}EndWord";
        Pattern patternOriginalSign = Pattern.compile(regEx, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        boolean OriginalStringMatchesPattern = patternOriginalSign.matcher(stringToMatch).matches();
        System.out.println(OriginalStringMatchesPattern);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the boundary \b that's specify a beginning or a ending of a word instead of [^a-z] which is not so logic.
Just something like

```
".*\\bfind\\b.*"
```